# Switching off IE8 Compatibility View

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, internet-explorer-8

I have a site which works fine when accessed from a remote web server. It runs (on IE8, which is what my organisation uses) with:

- Browser mode: Internet Explorer 8
- Document mode: Internet Explorer 8 Standards

However, when I open the same site from `localhost`, using the same browser, I get:

- Browser mode: Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View
- Document mode: Internet Explorer 7 Standards

With the tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`, I can fix the document mode to IE8. However I can't lose the Compatibility View - and this is causing some aspects of my site to break (specifically, some AJAX functionality).

Do you have any idea (a) why IE8 is rendering my site in Compatibility View from `localhost` when it renders normally on a remote server, and (b) how to prevent/circumvent this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You might have the option set under your IE options to use Compatibility view for local sites:
[image: Compatibility view settings]

From [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/compatibility-view-and-smart-defaults)